# Facebook PHP API for notifications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Let us suppose my website(www.1234.com) has two users A and B. The website www.1234.com has follow following functionality similar to twitter.

A is following B on www.1234.com and both A and B have facebook account. Now I have to implement notification system on facebook using facebook API

Case: A and B are not friends on facebook, is it possible to send notification to A on facebook when B does any activity on www.1234.com using facebook API, If yes then how?

Please help!

Comment: You can only send notifications to users that have connected to your app already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, you can only send notifications if you want. This is a restriction implemented by FB developers.

Thanks